# Мигание текста в TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, mvvm, wpf-шаблоны

Как сделать так, чтобы при изменении текста в `TextBlock`'e текст замигал, но при возврате к TargetNullValue анимация не срабатывала бы.

`XAML`:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding IdRemoteStdWinner, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, TargetNullValue='Победитель не найден!'}"
           FontSize="40"
           Margin="2"
           VerticalAlignment="Center"
           HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard Duration="0:0:5">
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                              FillBehavior="HoldEnd"
                                                              AutoReverse="True">
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                                        <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="Black"/>
                                        <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="White"/>
                                        <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="Black"/>
                                        <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="White"/>
                                        <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="Black"/>
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Ну так наверно привязывайте не к событию изменения, а к значению свойства и если оно `NULL`, то `<Setter Property = "Text" Value = "Победитель не найден!" />` и запуск своей анимации. Только вот точно не помню как `NULL` в триггере указывать, скорей всего нечто такое: `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SomeProperty}" Value="{x:Null}">`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Пробовал так, но не получилось. Сделал по-другому, ввёл две булевые переменные в VM и при помощи них манипулировал анимацией. На сколько правильное такое решение - не знаю)))

Comment: Правильно - не думаю, ибо дополнительные лишние значения. Ну если вам так удобно, то почему бы и нет.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ мне интересней, как правильно )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На вашем месте я бы сделал нечто такое:

```
<Style x:Key="TextBlock.TextBlink" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Text}"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text}" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="Некий текст"/>
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="BlinkAnimation"/>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard Name="BlinkAnimation">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True" Duration="0:0:0.1"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Как я говорил ранее в комментариях, вам надо при помощи `DataTrigger` проверять, равно-ли свойство `NULL`, если да, то анимация не требуется и мы ее можем вырубить. Делает в WPF это `RemoveStoryboard` (можно и с `PauseStoryboard` поиграться). Как видите, у `DataTrigger` есть `EnterActions` и `ExitActions`, тут думаю все понятно (в одном запускаем анимацию, в другом ее вырубаем).
Минус тут думаю очевиден, мы привязку делаем в стиле, что не есть хорошо. Увы, `TextBlock` не имеет `ContentTemplate` при помощи которого мы могли бы сделать `{TemplateBinding Text}`. Обходным решением будет стилизовать другой компонент, например `TextBox`, а лучше вовсе сделать свой контрол, где будет `DependencyProperty` с текстом.

Для проверки я лично набросаю такой интерфейс:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlock.TextBlink}" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="16"/>
    <TextBox BorderThickness="0 0 0 1" Width="150" Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Ну и собственно сам результат:

[image: Result]

А да, если у вас использование как у меня, то убедитесь, что привязанное свойство именно `NULL`, а не пустое, ибо когда вы удаляете все из `TextBox` (как у меня), то оно будет `Text = ""`, не `NULL`. Решается простой проверкой, на подобие:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) value = null;
```

в `Set` свойства. Если у вас используется лишь код, то пишите просто `Text = null;`, и этого достаточно.

Comment: Ох! Спасибо, за такой содержательный ответ. Действительно так интереснее. Но анимация срабатывает, когда первый раз изменяю значение св-ва. Если ориентироваться на Ваш пример, то как будто Вы написали 1 (анимация сработала), затем 2 и анимация уже не работает.

Comment: А, понял. Я поставил длительность анимации `RepeatBehavior = "0:0:3"`, a не `RepeatBehavior = "Forever"`. Дело в том, что это мигание, как уведомление. Т.е., когда не `null`, нужно помигать 3 секунды.

Answer (score 0):

Решение так себе, но работает:
`XAML`:

```
<Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" StretchDirection="DownOnly">
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding IdRemoteStdWinner, TargetNullValue='Игра запущена. Ждём ответов!'}">
    <TextBlock.Style>
      <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
          <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="40"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
              <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsAnimation}" Value="true">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                  <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                      <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames FillBehavior="Stop" RepeatBehavior="0:0:3">                                                                                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                       <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                         <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="Black"/>
                         <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="White"/>
                         <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="Black"/>
                         <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="White"/>
                         <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="Black"/>
                         <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="White"/>
                         <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="Black"/>
                       </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                      </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                     </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                   </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                  </DataTrigger>
             <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsAnimationEndGame}" Value="true">
              <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                 <Storyboard>
                  <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5"
                                  To="Transparent"
                                  FillBehavior="Stop"
                                  RepeatBehavior="0:0:3"
                                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"/>
                </Storyboard>
              </BeginStoryboard>
             </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
           </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
  </TextBlock>
</Viewbox>
```